# How to find all subsets which the total of elements is the same?

Tags: permutation

I want to find all subsets which the total of elements is the same.

For example, `Subsets[Range[30], {5}]` means all 5-element subsets and the range of each element is from 0 to 30. But I want to get the subsets which are only the total of elements equals to 30 (e.g., `{6, 6, 6 ,6, 6}`, `{7, 5, 6, 6, 6}`, ....

Answer (score 6):

```
Select[Subsets[Range[30], {5}], Total[#] == 30 &]
```

Will give you the desired subsets.

Note that for this particular kind of problem

```
Sort[Sort /@ Select[IntegerPartitions[30, {5}], Unequal @@ # &]]
```

will give you the same results, much more quickly.

Note that your question is ambiguous: `{6,6,6,6,6}` is *not* a "subset" by definition.

If you meant partitions, the following will do it:

```
IntegerPartitions[30, {5}]
```